# When to be concerned about a subordinate or employee

Tags: management, telecommute, software-development

I am a developer that is managing a small group. All members of this group, including myself are working remote. One member of this group that we'll call "Bob" is having trouble and very slow to respond. As an example I will ping him in the morning and not get a response until 9PM. Another example is that he was having trouble getting our application running locally and he didn't say he was having issues for 3 days.

It is early in the project and no one else has experience working with "Bob", yet my own boss is asking me for reports on the individual team members. Already my boss is concerned about "Bob". Any good ideas or metrics on when to be concerned about a subordinate and to what extent? I'd also like to know any methods to help get "Bob" engaged without needing to fire/punish him.

Comment: Ping them in the morning and not get a reply until 9pm? If that's true, I would ask if they were sick, and if so, why he didn't report it to you. Be a manager and tell that person if he does it again, that you would recommend firing him.

Comment: When to be concerned about a subordinate or employee? I think it's when you ping the employee in the morning and only get a response by 9pm.

Comment: Threatening to fire / punish him is a bit harsh if you haven't spoken with him about it already. I would say, just have a word with him and explain that you need timely responses to your emails and that issues that are causing potential delays (such as not being able to get the application running!) need to be flagged ASAP.

Comment: Just to be sure you're all on the same time zone right?

Comment: @Dan 1 hour time difference. Though he's still well outside of the company's "working"/operating hours for these late night responses. These responses appeared to be an attempt to show that he was working hard and late. The only thing was when I would reply within minutes of his 9pm response he'd go silent again until the next day.

Comment: @GustavoMP I dare say that not doing any actual work for 3 days also counts. To be honest OP, without a valid reason this kind of behaviour should be grounds for immediate dismissal, not efforts to improve (non-existing) performance.

Comment: It should be noted that some people prefer different forms of communication. Some prefer email, some IM some the phone. Perhaps he only checks email once or twice a day. Why not just phone/IM him instead?

Comment: I noticed that your first paragraph alternates between references to "Bob"  and "them"/"they".  Should "them" be "him"? Your pronoun choices don't make it clear when you are referring to your team vs when you referring to only Bob.

Comment: @codenoire I agree and I've edited it accordingly.  There's no need to use gender neutral when the pseudonym is male. We get that "Bob" could actually be "Bobbi" and it doesn't affect the answers.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep I don't know if it's appropriate for you to guess at the OP's actual intent in this case - that could skew things.

Comment: It's an edit for clarity. Myself, I had to reread it to make sure OP wasn't talking about the team. when using they/them. I feel like we're playing the "pronoun game" to no benefit.  :)  ( http://www.subzin.com/quotes/M135526e2b/Chasing+Amy/Why+are+you+playing+the+pronoun+game%3F ) A close read shows the intent remains.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will need to communicate your concerns to Bob, and sooner rather than later.

I'm assuming that you guys have certain hours when you're supposed to be online, and working. At any point during that time you should be able to contact this guy and get a reply within a reasonable time frame.

The next time he fails to respond in a timely manner, call him. You should be able to get a hold of him and ask him why he isn't replying. Explain to him that his delays in replying are unacceptable, and something which is worrying the rest of the team.

Also try imposing tighter deadlines on him. If you know a task should only take a day to complete, ask for an update the following morning. Express your expectations, and make sure to follow up. In other words put some pressure on this guy to shape up.

If, however, Bob simply does not improve, and continues to be an unreliable employee you may consider installing tracking software on his machine. It's perfectly normal for a company to keep track of what's being done with its hardware. Maybe you guys should keep track of Bob's  internet history and times when he is active on his work machine. If it doesn't match what expected results, then you know that he is being dishonest, and should probably get rid of him.

Comment: Talking to them directly is the right response. If doing so provides any information that may be helpful I will post it here. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Two phrases to use:  "I've been asked to talk with you about ..." - Be intentionally vague.  Let him know it's an issue noticed above you.  Don't let him know how high above you.  Second: "Core Hours" - If Bob is used to contracting, and working his own hours, he may not understand that being employed as part of a team requires your attendance during certain hours.  Make this clear.  Present it matter-of-fact, not as a topic for discussion.

Comment: @WesleyLong Why hide behind a vague statement like that? OP is the manager, he doesn't need an excuse to talk about a report's performance. That's called managing.

Comment: @Lilienthal - It's not about "hiding."  It's about choosing your ground for a potential conflict.  If the employee thinks it's just coming from you, then he can make it personal (at least in his mind).  If it's clear it's coming from the organization, that's a more nebulous concept, and it is clear it's more than just one person.  That couches any further discussion very differently.  Also, if the employee corrects his behavior, then you haven't made it personal, so you're likely to have better interaction with him in the future, as he'll (rightly) think that for you, it's over and dealt with.

Comment: I agree with @WesleyLong but it really depends on the authority that the OP has, etc.

Comment: @WesleyLong Anyone who can't deal with constructive feedback in the workplace needs to adjust their mindset. Receiving and responding to feedback is a critical skill for any form of employment. This isn't a conflict and we're not talking about a playground here but about managing functional adults.

Comment: @Lilienthal - I don't know where "playground" came into the discussion.  Using psychology in management is (at least I thought) a given.  It's also pretty basic strategy:  If you anticipate a conflict or a potential conflict, you need to choose the terms to your advantage as best you can.  If everyone were "functional adults," about 2/3rds of this site wouldn't exist.

Comment: @WesleyLong I made the reference because you don't need to treat employees like children. This site is based on minority events and just because we see a lot of dysfunctional colleagues and environments here that doesn't make them the norm. I'd rather treat employees normally instead of playing mindgames as if they could melt down at any moment over a bit of criticism. The wonderful part of being a manager is that if you discover someone who refuses to act like an adult you can just replace them. You can manage your employees, you don't have to manage around them.

Comment: @Lilienthal - at no point did I mention treating anyone like children.  This isn't about mindgames.  It's about keeping the issue from becoming personal.  If the issue becomes personal, and not objective, then the actual issue becomes nothing but a proxy for a personal conflict.  I try to avoid the personal conflict entirely.

Comment: @WesleyLong And my point is that anyone who can't receive feedback without making it personal and turning that into a conflict is not worth keeping on staff. In most cases simply doing your job shouldn't cause a conflict. It seems we fundamentally disagree but ping me on [chat] if you want to discuss this further as I think we're going off-topic here.

Comment: "Core Hours" is a good concept. Need to make expectations clear.

Comment: I agree with lillenthal.  A subordinate that isn't doing their work should be about as personal as it can get.  Be straight with them about their performance.  They'll either get the message and fix it or be mad and move on.  Either is a good solution.

Comment: I'm against tracking employees. I just think it's lazy management, and it doesn't help to improve code, infact it has the reverse effect on code because lines of codes and time spend in the IDE can both be gamed by lazy employees.